# XML binding in Dart

Tags: xml, parsing, dart

There is any way in Dart to parse XML and obtain an object?

For example if I have this XML:

```
<person>
 <name>John</name>
 <surname>Smith</surname>
</person>
```

I want to bind it to this object:

```
class Person {
 String name;
 String surname;
  ...
}
```

With a snippet like this:

```
Person person = parse(xml);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box.

Here is currently an extensive discussion going on about serialization/deserialization: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/0pv-Uaq8FGI

The discussion is mostly about JSON but most of it applies to XML as well.

Answer (score 1):

I made a pub package that transforms xml to objects with objectbuilders. Maybe that is what you are searching for! https://github.com/jorishermans/xmlstream

You always need to tell the system how you want to transform your xml to the dart object.